# In a mortar or with a mortar? In a juicer or with a juicer?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference in usage, or is one of them correct whilst the other not?

> To grind an acorn *in*/*with* a mortar.
>
> To juice an orange *in*/*with* a juicer.

Comment: Both are OK. using -> with. as a receptacle-> in.

Comment: One of the wonderful things about English is that it is a language which always seems to provide the speaker/writer with plentiful options. Enjoy the use of variety!

Comment: I disagree with the comments so far. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To grind an acorn in a mortar.* (Correct)

*To grind an acorn with a mortar.* (Grammatically possible but highly unlikely. You grind something **in** a mortar **with** a pestle.)

*To juicing an orange in/with a juicer.*  (Incorrect)

You cannot use the collocation 'to juicing' in this way. It should be 'to juice'.

*To juice an orange with a juicer.* (Correct)

*To juice an orange in a juicer.* (Ambiguous. It would be possible (although admittedly unlikely) to juice something inside a juicer without operating the mechanism of the juicer.)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - But I bet you would accept *to grind an acorn with [a] mortar and pestle*.  (Just shows the choice of equipment.)

Comment: @aparente001 - Yes I would. However you can grind something using a pestle alone on almost any flat or concave surface. It is difficult to grind an acorn with a mortar alone unless you use the base to crush it against another surface. Doable but rather awkward.

Comment: Are you trying to be cute, or did you understand the OP was going to work with a mortar and no pestle?

Comment: @aparente001 - Read my answer.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, you have the pestle in there.  Anyway, my point is, I think "with a mortar and pestle" works just as well as "cleaning the floor with a mop and bucket" does.

Comment: I've already agreed with that in my previous comment. (?)